# Prove $\tilde d: M\to \mathbb{R}; x\mapsto \tilde d(x) = d(x,A)$ is continous

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of a certain metric space $M$.
>
> Prove that $\tilde d: M\to \mathbb{R}; x\mapsto \tilde d(x) = d(x,A)$ is continous. (where $d(x,a) = \inf\{d(x,a): a\in A\}$)
>
> Then use this to prove that $B(A,r)$ is open in $M$.

I've got some ideas on how to prove this statement, but I'm not entirely sure. Could someone verify?

- The second part of the statement is easily shown.
  If $\tilde d$ is continous, then since ${]-\infty, r[}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}, \tilde d^{-1}({]-\infty, r[})$ must be open in $M$.
- Because the second part uses the transformation of open sets into open sets I want to tackle the first part using $\varepsilon, \delta$ style.

[image: mental picture]

My intention is to prove continuïty in $\alpha\in M$:

$$(\forall \varepsilon)(\exists \delta)(\forall x \in B(\alpha, \delta))(|\tilde d(x)-\tilde d(\alpha)|<\varepsilon)$$

1 If $\alpha \in A$ then $d(\alpha,A)=0$. Then choose $\delta = \varepsilon$.

2 If $\alpha \not \in A$ then $d(\alpha,A)\not = 0$.

Now note that $$\begin{align}
d(\alpha, A)-d(x,A) &= \inf\{ d(\alpha, a):a\in A\}-\inf\{d(x,a): a \in A\}\\
&= \inf\{ d(\alpha, a) - d(x,a): a \in A\}\\
&\leqslant \inf\{d(\alpha, x): a \in A\} = d(x,\alpha)
\end{align}$$

Let $d(x,\alpha) < \delta = \varepsilon$.

#### Remarks

It seems logical to choose the $\delta$ ball to have a radius of less then $\varepsilon$, but I think the reasoning with the infimums is faulty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Be careful, the inequality 
$$\inf\{ d(\alpha, a):a\in A\}-\inf\{d(x,a): a \in A\}
\le \inf\{ d(\alpha, a) - d(x,a): a \in A\}$$
need not hold. Let for example $\alpha=0,\ x=2,\ A=\{1,2.5\}$. Then the left side of the equation is $0.5$ while the right side is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove $\tilde{d}$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

By triangle inequality, for every $a \in A$:

$$d(x_0,a) \leq d(x_0, x)+ d(x,a)$$

$$\implies d(x_0,A) \leq d(x_0,x)+d(x,a) \quad (2)$$

, since $d(x_0,A) \leq d(x_0,a)$

But $d(x_0,A)$ is constant, and the inequality $(2)$ holds for every $a$. Therefore,

$$d(x_0,A) \leq \inf_{a \in A} \{d(x_0,x)+d(x,a)\}=d(x_0,x)+ \inf_{a \in A}\{d(x,a)\}=d(x_0,x)+d(x,A)$$

Which implies:

$$d(x_0, A)-d(x,A) \leq d(x_0,x)$$

Switchting places between $x_0$ and $x$ (which can be done since triangular inequality holds for all elements of the metric space):

$$d(x,A)-d(x_0,A) \leq d(x,x_0)$$

We then get $|d(x,A)-d(x_0,A)|< d(x,x_0)$

By the previous considerations, taking $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is enough.

Answer (score 0):

We have $d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$. So $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$. It is nonexpansive and therefore Lipschitz continuous.